# What does the CategorySources plugin do?

Tags: plugins

A little off-topic, but wondering if someone can shed some light on the [CategorySources](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/CategorySources) plugin.

A client site has hundreds of articles (in an 'articles' structure) that are currently assigned to categories via a categories field. It would be great if they could view the articles by category (which I assume is what the plugin is for?). I installed, activated, and selected the category groups in the plugin settings, but I'm not seeing any obvious changes to the CP. Where are these mysterious category sources? Or am I missing the point? The plugin docs are a bit light on specifics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, the plugin serves two purposes... one of which is simply to serve as an example for how to use the [`modifyEntrySources` hook](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntrySources).

Beyond that, the plugin will provide you with an alternative way to view your Entries. You'll notice that the categories which you selected now appear as **entry sources** on the left sidebar under the Entries tab.

Oh, and [Craft 2.3.2629 is required...](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2629) that's when `modifyEntrySources` was introduced.

Comment: I'm getting old... you beat me.

Comment: http://blodsmak.no/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/great-success-borat-macro-yes-1275741053s.jpg

Comment: hmmm... that's what I assumed as well. But I'm on the entries index page and see nothing in the left hand column. Must be broke?! I assume it works with entries defined in both channels and structures?

Comment: Triple-check that the plugin is enabled and the Category Groups you want are selected in the plugin's settings. It's working great for me! If you're still having problems, maybe file a bug report with P&T.

Comment: Oh, and [**Craft 2.3.2629** is required...](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2629) that's when `modifyEntrySources` was introduced.

Comment: haha... ah yes... having a version of craft which supports categorySources would probably help a lot! Just updated. Much better. Thanks.

Comment: speaking of which, it would probably be good to have a craft dependency variable you could define in your plugin, that craft would check against the version and prevent installation.

Comment: It's up on Github... I'm sure a pull request would be welcome. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The plugin is mainly an example of how to use the new [modifyEntrySources](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#modifyEntrySources) hook.

Go to the entry index page and you should have the category groups you selected in the menu on the left hand side.

If so, click one of the categories in the left hand menu and you'll see any entries that have category fields with them selected.